# How to upload images using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

My controller function is

```
 <?php 
    class Image extends CI_Controller
    {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('image');
    }
    public function upload()
    {
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']    = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
    $error = array('error' =>$this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('image',$error);
     }
    else
    {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
     }
     }
     }
     ?>
```

My view function is

```
  <?php echo $error; ?>
  <?php
  echo form_open_multipart('image/upload');  ?>
  <input name="myFile" size="40" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Note: In codeigniter you do not need to close your controllers  `?>`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
```

Use as following. Use field name in `do_upload()` method

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('myFile'))
```